# What would cause "Connection Refused" with simplest nginx centos setup on GCE?

Tags: nginx, firewall, reverse-proxy, google-cloud-platform, node.js

### Update

I followed the same steps as below except on a generic VPS provided ( Not google ) and it worked as anticipated including unlisted steps such as enabling HTTPS with Certbot... So my presumption is there is some special configuration in the GCE thing that I am misunderstanding/misusing/not doing that is causing the issue described below. Any ideas as to what that thing could bein GCE?

### Setup

I have a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance with Debian installed on it. I have by default, during the setup of this GCE instance, allowed HTTP and HTTPS traffic via the provided GCE firewall options. I entered into the GCE instance via SSH and did the following :

Screen shot of GCE http/https permission granting [Evidence of GCE permitting the traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7kZp.png)

1.) Installed nginx and ufw

```
sudo apt install nginx ufw
```

2.) Enabled UFW's rules allowing HTTP, HTTPS, and SSH connections

```
sudo ufw allow (http/https/ssh)
sudo systemctl enable ufw
sudo systemctl start ufw
```

3.) Enabled nginx leaving the default configuration

```
sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo nginx -t ( returned "ok" results )
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

4.) Ensured my domain was pointed at the right IP

### Tests

**Curling tests**

When I visit the domain I still get a "domain.com refused to connect" error
If I execute

```
curl localhost
```

I get the expected default content
If I enter

**Netstat check**

```
netstat -a
```

I can see that I am listening to the outside world on the proper ports

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

**UFW check**

If I check my firewall rules I see the following

```
sudo ufw status
SSH                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
224.0.0.251 mDNS           ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
SSH (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
ff02::fb mDNS              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Which I believe indicates my ports are opened correctly.

**Ping Check**

I can ping my server by the domain and it returns correctly with the expected IP.

```
Pinging FizzBuzz.app [cor.rec.t.IP] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from cor.rec.t.IP: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=57
Reply from cor.rec.t.IP: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=57
Reply from cor.rec.t.IP: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=57
Reply from cor.rec.t.IP: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=57

Ping statistics for cor.rec.t.IP:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 33ms, Maximum = 34ms, Average = 33ms
```

**Logging Check**

When I visit /var/log/nginx/error.log it is empty ( after visiting the domain with a failed result )

When I visit /var/log/nginx/access.log it has a single entry for when I checked if "curl localhost" worked ( which it did )

So as best as I can tell nginx isn't showing any errors.

### Conclusion

As of right now I have exhausted all possible avenues to resolve this issue except for shelling out for Google support directly... I am attempting to use the most simple usecase possible in order to minimize variables and am still finding myself with a "refused to connect" error when visiting my site via the IP or the Domain when it is hosted by Google, when I have it hosted by 2 other providers it works just fine. Conclusion? I am befuddled...

Comment: Nothing in your included nginx config here is related to port 443.  Additionally, if you simply did 'curl localhost', then you hit the default port 80.  There's no evidence here that port 443 is even in use other than your firewall is set to permit it.

Comment: @yoonix Let me rectify that! Thank you for pointing that out. I will report back on my question once I see what happens.

Comment: @Dapper have you looked nginx logs? Is the refused request being listed on nginx logs? If not, sounds you didn't properly configured GCP firewall rules

Comment: @surfingonthenet I just checked again after redoing the setup entirely, no such luck in the logs. I have further expanded my post in the hopes of illuminating the situation more including screenshot of GCE showing "yes" to http/https . I am very appreciative of your replies thus far, thank you

Comment: What is the domain name? What is the IP address?

Comment: @Dapper, so, first point is configuring GCP firewall in a way your request can reach your server. If you enabled "HTTP" connection on the VM instance, confirm you firewall rule "default-allow-http" allow your computer as a source, in the right VPC

Comment: @surfingonthenet Dear friend I have found the solution! Look with glee at my answering post as I have slain my dragon! :D Thank you so much for keeping me at this and figuring it out with me! The spare brain space is wonderfully appreciated everyone!

Comment: @Dapper I'm glad you sorted this out. Awesome! About SSL, access https://get.acme.sh and use the command in my post below

Comment: Duly noted I will apply that method for the .app domain, cheers good sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 3 main points in your question: nodejs app as backend, nginx not listening on port 443, and reverse-proxy configuration. Let's break it down to look to each point isolated.

1. nodejs app: try accessing it from localhost and confirm it's answering properly

> curl http://127.0.0.1/3000

2. nginx not listening on port 443: You must configure a server block on nginx for that, and, it's also a good ideia redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS:

> ```
> server {
>     listen 80 default_server;
>     server_name fizzbuzz.app www.fizzbuzz.app;
>     return 301 https://fizzbuzz.app$request_uri;
> }
>
>
> server {
>     listen 8443 ssl;
>     server_name fizzbuzz.app www.fizzbuzz.app;
>
>     index index.html index.htm;
>
>     access_log /var/log/nginx/fizzbuzz-access.log;
>     error_log /var/log/nginx/fizzbuzz-error.log error;
>
>      location / {
>         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
>         proxy_http_version 1.1;
>         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
>         proxy_set_header Host $host;
>         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
>      }
>
>     ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/fizzbuzz.app-fullchain.pem;
>     ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/fizzbuzz.app.key;
> }
> ```

For issuing your certificate, I suggest you use certbot or one ACME script.

i.e. using acme.sh you can issue a certificate using the command:

> ```
> /root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue --nginx -d fuzzbuzz.app -d www.fuzzbuzz.ap
>
> /root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --install-cert -d fuzzbuzz.app -d www.fuzzbuzz.app \
> --cert-file /etc/ssl/certs/fuzzbuzz.app.crt \
> --key-file /etc/ssl/certs/fuzzbuzz.app.key \
> --fullchain-file ${CERTS_DIR}/fuzzbuzz.app-fullchain.pem \
> --log /var/log/acme_log \
> --reloadcmd "systemctl restart nginx"
> ```

Having issued your certificate and having it in place, restart nginx e test it

3. The third point is configuring nginx as reverse proxy for exposing your application over HTTPS. I think the configuration above should work. Case it doesn't, I do suggest you reading this doc from GoCD that explains exactly this kind of config:

[Configure a Reverse Proxy](https://docs.gocd.org/current/installation/configure-reverse-proxy.html)

Comment: Your reply encouraged me to redo and simplify my approach ( removed SSL from the equation for now ). I was able to confirm NodeJS and Nginx functionality individually and working together, at least locally , this time.

Comment: @Dapper, I'm glad that helped you and it's working. Anyway, I'd like to encourage you to configure the SSL block as well. It's not a big deal, I can nail it

Comment: I have further reduced my situation down to just having the Nginx "hello world" appear when I visit my domain and I still get connection refused... If you have any advisements based on my updated post I would appreciate it, if you have the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!!

.APP! It was the .app TLD this entire time!!!

I was heading off to buy a random domain name to provide a name and IP to a commenter , selected a .app one just for kicks( had a silly name thought up for this testing ) and I read this : ".APP is a secure namespace. You may purchase Foobarington.app now but it will require an SSL certificate for website connection. Learn more about secure namespaces and how to get an SSL certificate

SO! When I tried pointing my .app domain at the server it wouldn't load because my server at that point didn't have an SSL Certificate. I intended on using CertBot to get the certificate but they require http access initially to do the automated certificate granting thing.

I need to figure out how to get Certbot ( or equivalent solution ) to function for me using this TLD type and host but it is definitely the TLD type that I have that yielded this problem!

Comment: I doubt it was the .app TLD per se. There's nothing "secure" about a domain namespace that makes, say, .app more secure than .org. It's just that you don't have a certificate set up, so https didn't work. Try "curl http ://FizzBuzz.App" and see if that works.  (Remove the space after http --- I couldn't figure out any other way to defeat StackExchange's "smart" formatting)

Comment: @TheodoreTs'o I thought similarly but after digging around some I found this : ( https://icannwiki.org/.app ) , if you scroll to "mandatory HTTPS" you'll find the line that reads as follows " Non-HTTPS-protected sites on the list therefore not load at all, rather than the typical fallback behavior of displaying an insecure site " , so for these unique TLDs we have to enable HTTPS before using them